# PHP: How to deal with "read data timeout in 31 seconds" error?

Tags: wordpress, http, google-apps-script

I am trying to send my WP site's user infos to a google sheet.

```
function updateUsersToSheet($api_url,$ids = NULL){
  if (!isset($ids)) {
    $users = get_users();
    $admins = [1,7,29,30,35,40];
    foreach ($users as $user ){
      if (!in_array($user->ID,$admins)) {
        $data = getWPUserData($user);
        sendGetToSheet($data,$api_url);
      }
    }
  } else {
    $ids = is_array($ids)?$ids:array($ids);
    foreach($ids as $id) {
      $user = get_user_by('ID',$id);
      $data = getWPUserData($user,1);
      sendGetToSheet($data,$api_url);
    }
  }
}

function sendGetToSheet($data,$api_url){
  $get_query = "?".http_build_query($data);
  $res = file_get_contents($api_url.$get_query);
  if ($res) {
    mylogfunction($res);
   
  } else {
    // echo 'failed';
    $to = 'shenkwen@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'There has been an error in sendGet';
    $message = json_encode($res);
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    $s = wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
  }
}
```

On the google sheet's side, I have deployed the Apps script as a web app and in `doGet()` I have something like

```
userSheet.getRange(myRange).setValues([[last_name,first_name,phone,email,degree,roles,church,cn_name,bday,gender]]);
```

The code works fine if I just update one user, but if I want to update multiple users by calling `updateUsersToSheet($api_url)`, the google sheet will only update several users. And I see that there is an error on my web server saying

> read data timeout in 31 seconds

I have put these two lines into my code

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 900);
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 900);
```

but still get the same error. I think manually put a wait time in the foreach loop might help; also another possible fix is to get all users' info and send them in one go. Is there any other better ways to fix it?

Comment: About `also another possible fix is to get all users' info and send them in one go`, when this is reflected in your script, what result did you obtain?

Comment: @Tanaike I haven't got a chance to try it so far

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `@Tanaike I haven't got a chance to try it so far`, how about testing it?

Comment: Yes I will. My goal of this question is not to solve the problem though. It is to figure out how this error is generated and is there any way to to avoid it such as ini_set

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `It is to figure out how this error is generated`, in this case, it is required to confirm the detailed information for correctly replicating your situation. But, unfortunately, I have no information now. But, I would like to try to understand your situation. When I could correctly understand your situation for correctly replicating your current issue, I would like to think of the reason for it and a solution. I apologize that I have no clear answer now.